# JS Web Worker is a macro task?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

In which queue browsers handle WebWorkers? Microtasks, Macrotasks, or a dedicated one?

We know that things such as `setTimeout` and `setInterval` are macrotasks, and `Promises` are microtasks. But I can't find any information regarding WebWorkers and the `message` event.

```
var worker = new Worker('doWork.js');

worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  console.log('Worker said: ', e.data);
}, false);

worker.postMessage('Hello World');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question seems to come from a few misunderstandings.

---

First a bit of hair splitting on nomenclature, but there is nothing named "*macro-task*". Only ["*task*"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#concept-task) and ["*microtask*"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#microtask) are part of the [HTML specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html), responsible for the Event loops in a browser.
This point has some sense since you need to understand that *microtasks* are just normal *tasks* that get executed at a special moment in the [event-loop](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model).

Basically, after each [task execution](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model:concept-task-steps), the browser will [perform a microtask endpoint](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#perform-a-microtask-checkpoint) which will check if there are pending *microtasks* to get executed.

This is the only difference between a *microtask* and a *task*.

So asking if something runs in a *microtask* or in a task makes very little sense. To make something run in a *microtask* all you need is to call it from [`queueMicroTask()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/queueMicrotask)*, but once again, that won't change anything.

---

The [creation of a Worker](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#worker-processing-model) is asynchronous (it needs to [fetch the script](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#worker-processing-model:fetch-a-classic-worker-script)) and thus does span on multiple tasks, on [different processes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#worker-processing-model-top), and on [different event loops](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#worker-processing-model:responsible-event-loop) (though they use the same [processing model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model)).

So saying if it runs in a microtask... The synchronous part could.

```js
queueMicrotask( () => {
  // Worker instance is created from a micro-task...
  const worker = new Worker('data:application/javascript,const foo="bar";');
} );
```

---

Now, IMM the most interesting point of this question is about the **message event**.

Indeed, we already saw that we only have *tasks*, however what we didn't say is that there are several [*task queues*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#task-queue) and most importantly, **all task queues don't have the same priority!**

There is an [ongoing proposal](https://github.com/WICG/main-thread-scheduling/blob/master/PrioritizedPostTask.md) to give control over these priorities to web-devs, but that's still a proposal.

I must admit that for the time being what happens is not always clear science to me, but basically the [posted message task source](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-messaging.html#posted-message-task-source) comes from one of the *tasks queues* with highest priority we have access to (IIRC after animation frames).

Concretely this does mean that if you schedule two asynchronous tasks from the same event loop, the *message event* should win, even though it's been called after:

```js
setTimeout( () => console.log( 'timeout' ), 0 );
onmessage = e => console.log( 'message' );
postMessage( '', '*' );
```

*<sub>which is also available in Workers, so Promises are not the only way to run microtasks in a Worker.</sub>

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that wasn't "snark" I'm sorry you did read it like that and I will remove it right away. However, your answer does state a few imprecisions, like you are saying the Worker is executed from a macrotask, that's not true, you are talking about JavaScript, the event loops and Workers are not written in JavaScript and ECMA has like almost no influence on the current matter, you state that Worker can only execute microtasks coming from a Promise reaction, while they also have access to `global.queueMicroTask`.

Comment: Thank you for removing it. I said "I think" the only microtasks in web workers are promise reactions. If that's not true (and [it seems not to be](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/queueMicrotask) -- how recent is that?), all that's needed is a comment pointing that out. I don't think our characterizations of how a worker is initially run are fundamentally in conflict. You're looking at it differently and perhaps in more detail, but fundamentally, the top-level execution of a script is a script job, which is fundamentally a task.

Comment: [queueMicrotask proposal](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/512) was closed in 2018. Firefox did implement it quite recently, Chrome had it before. But I really thought that was a minor imprecision, and my first sentence was meant to mean that your answer was *correct*, but that it missed the real points of the question which to me is that microtasks are not magic and that onmessage kinda is ;-)

Comment: I will note that the ECMAScript spec recently got changed to back off defining the processing of jobs too precisely, I think in response to feedback from implementers who found it overly prescriptive, which was fine because the definition didn't need to be as firm as we it was.

Comment: Thanks for that, I figured it was quite recent. :-) And yes, I should have explained the message event aspect. It's bigger in the question than I initially read.

Comment: I hope you and yours are well in these...seriously unsettling times.

Comment: Thanks, I wish the best for you too.

Answer (score 3):

Workers run their own event loop in their own thread, which runs both macrotasks and microtasks. (That's HTML spec terminology [except they just use *task* and *microtask*]; tasks are script jobs and microtasks are promise jobs in JavaScript spec terms.) The job to run the worker initially is a (macro)task, as is the event callback in your code. <s>For the moment I think the only microtasks in web workers are promise reactions.</s> Actually no, [Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido) points out we now have [`queueMicroTask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/queueMicrotask) in workers as well.

Details in [*The event loop*](https://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#the-event-loop) in the web workers spec, and the [jobs section](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-jobs) of the JavaScript spec.